# Is there a utility for converting RVM default.gems files to Bundler Gemfiles?

Tags: rubygems, rvm, bundler

If I'm setting up a project to use Bundler, and I already have an RVM gemset for the project, is there an easy way to export the gemset list to `Gemfile` (or, for that matter, convert the `default.gems` file to a `Gemfile` format)? Or are we all just find-and-replacing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a command in rvm for that:

```
rvm gemset export Gemfile
```

It will generate `Gemfile` with all the gems in gemset.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to generate a Gemfile for an old rails project and I wrote this little script to help me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#Save in file to_gemfile.rb
gem_file = File.open("Gemfile", "w")
gem_file.write("source :rubygems\n")
  STDIN.readlines.each do |line|
    line = line.chomp
    line =~ /(.*)\s\((.*)\)/
    gem_name = $1
    versions = $2.split(",")
    gem_file.write("gem \"#{gem_name}\", \"#{versions.first}\"\n")
  end
gem_file.close
```

Use it like so

```
$ gem list | ./to_gemfile.rb
```

Comment: Hey, this is pretty close to what I'm after! The only missing link is that this does require the gems to be already installed (that is, I'd need to import the gemset before generating the `Gemfile`) but that can probably be managed by adapting the script to read the default.gems file instead of the piped output of `gem list`.

Comment: I'm not sure how the default.gems format looks like but if it is close to what gem list produces you could do `./to_gemfile.rb < default.gems`

Comment: @user420504 it's like `gem install ...` but with stripped `gem install `, so you can specify there `--version` or `-v` and additional compilation flags if needed

Answer (score 3):

run "bundle install" !

it will use the gems which were installed under RVM on the command line (if they are installed already)

check Ryan Bates RailsCast on Bundler: http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler

Comment: If the gems were already installed, though, why would I need to `bundle install`? What I'm hoping for is a `Gemfile` I can check in to SCM so the rest of my team gets the changes as well, the way we did with `default.gems`. Maybe I need to `bundle install` and then export to `Gemfile`?

Comment: the 'bundle install' wraps-up and freezes your gems by generating the Gemfile.lock file -- so you don't accidentially mix unwanted versions..  
Check for more info here:  http://gembundler.com/ , e.g. the "Understanding Bundler" tab

Comment: I gave this a try. If I don't already have a `Gemfile`, `bundle install` returns an error ("could not locate Gemfile"). If I have a blank one, `bundle install` doesn't create it. What I was hoping to find was a path from no `Gemfile` but a project-specific RVM gemset, to having a `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` which reflect that RVM gemset, without manually listing the gems again in the `Gemfile`.

Comment: well, the bundler can't really guess which versions you want -- that's what the Gemfile is for -- you should list the versions you want, then run 'bundle install'

Comment: :) The versions are listed in the `.rvmrc` file, which is exactly why I was hoping there was a utility to generate one file from the other.

Comment: nope, that's not how you use Bundler... you need to specify in Gemfile which versions you think are stable for your application.   your ~/.rvm/ directory may contain multiple different versions of each gem.  Check the RailsCast on Bundler: http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler

Comment: Right, but if we have per-project `.rvmrc` files they should already specify the version which are used for that project.

Comment: Oops - I wrote `.rvmrc` when I meant `default.gems`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [rails_upgrade](https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade) plugin provides this capability through its `rake rails:upgrade:gems` task. Its description of this rake task is that it will:

> Generate a Gemfile from your config.gem directives